# OpenCV gives an error in the Jupyter Notebook but works in Python CLI

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter, importerror

So, I am using OpenCV in python. I installed `opencv-python` using `pip install opencv-python`. Whenever I try importing OpenCV in my terminal using the Python CLI (run `python` in command prompt and then run `import cv2`) it works perfectly fine, but when I try importing it in Jupyter Notebook/Jupyter Lab (also using `import cv2`), it gives the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-c8ec22b3e787> in <module>
----> 1 import cv2

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py in <module>
      1 import importlib
      2 
----> 3 from .cv2 import *
      4 from .data import *
      5 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2.cv2'
```

I know that there is already a thread on this ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55360459/no-module-named-cv2-cv2)) but I tried everything in that thread and nothing worked. I also saw [this](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/186) (I do have a `pyd` file in that directory) and [this](https://github.com/Breakthrough/PySceneDetect/issues/73) (nothing works) and even [this](https://github.com/udacity/P1_Facial_Keypoints/issues/13) (installing `nb_conda` and `jupyter` don't do anything). Please help!

**EDIT:** Here are some more things I tried:

- `conda install -c anaconda opencv` - doesn't change anything
- use a `venv` - already tried, doesn't change anything

**EDIT 2:** Looks like this issue is only with `jupyter notebook` whenever a library uses `.` to import something. For example, the error here occurs when `opencv` tries to import `.cv2`. I also have posted another question a few days ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62735623/stable-baselines-doesnt-work-with-tensorflow) about `stable-baselines` not working in `jupyter notebook`, and the problem with that was that the module was trying to import `from . import _ufuncs` (another `.` import). **Do others have this problem in Jupyter Notebook? Also, should I make a new StackOverflow post on `.` imports?**

~ Ayush

Comment: You are using Anaconda.  Have you tried doing `conda install -c anaconda opencv`?

Comment: @rayryeng Yes, I have, but it doesn't change anything... The same error occurs on jupyter notebook but not in Python CLI

Comment: How are you launching the notebook server?  And when you launch the notebook file itself, are you picking the system Python or the Anaconda Python?

Comment: I use the command `jupyter notebook` in my cmd.

Comment: check the kernel on jupyter notebook, and remember to swap the venv before you launch `jupyter notebook` on cmd

Comment: I am not using a `venv`, although I did try one and it didn't work. Also, yes, the kernel is in my main Python 3 env where I installed `opencv-python`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! I got the answer!!

So, when I looked at `__init__.py` in the `cv2` library, I found this line:

```
from .cv2 import *
```

So, I changed it to:

```
from cv2.cv2 import *
```

and everything works now! Hope this helps other people in the future!